# Change Windows 10 "from" address for Gmail

Tags: windows-10, gmail, email-client

I have just upgraded to Windows 10. In Win7 I would usually use Gmail in the browser. I use Gmail to send emails on behalf of my own domain name (so I have a Gmail address, but it sends from my personal domain address). I can't find a setting in Windows 10 (using the default Mail & Calendar app) to change the `From` address in the mail client.

Is it possible?

Comment: I am using the default Mail & Calendar app that comes with Windows 10.

Comment: @fixer1234: Win10 absolutely does have email settings; it's part of the "Settings" app under "Accounts" -> "Email & app accounts". The default Win10 mail client app (which uses these settings; it has no settings of its own distinct from those OS-controlled ones) is called "Outlook Mail" in the app list, and is part of the "Mail and Calendar" [app bundle on the store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/mail-and-calendar/9wzdncrfhvqm).

Comment: It's unlikely. However, you may add another mail account with your domain email, then you'll be able to select account you use to send mail. Yet in this case, the sent email won't appear in Gmail's Sent folder.