# Change "From" address in Win10 "Outlook Mail" app

Tags: windows-10, email, gmail, google-workspace, windows-10-mail-app

I'm using the built-in "Outlook Mail and Calendar" app on Win10, as my employer uses G-Suite (formerly Google Apps) and the Office version of Outlook doesn't know how to use OAuth or sync Google calendars or contacts. I have a number of aliases on that account that are different from my sign-in account (I sign in with "A@corp.com" but also own "B@corp.com" and "C@corp.com"). I can't get Outlook Mail to send from those accounts, though! I can do it through the Gmail web app, but not through the thick client.

At a minimum, I want to change the default "From" address to "B@corp.com" even though I sign in with "A@corp.com"; I don't care that much about being able to send from "A@corp.com" or "C@corp.com". I was able to do this on the web app, but the Outlook Mail app isn't respecting this setting; it always sends from "A@corp.com" because that's the sign-in address. I can't add the other addresses as their own accounts, either (not that I really want to; I'd get all my mail multiple times) because I can't sign in as "B@corp.com"; it's an email alias, not a separate account.

The best thing I've found is a registry key that *ought* to control these settings: `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\ActiveSync\Partners\{<GUID>}`. It contains values such as the following:

```
AccountType: Gmail
Email:       A@corp.com
Name:        Corp Google Apps
Server:      imap.gmail.com:993:1
```

(and many others). If I change the "Name" of the account (using the Settings -> Accounts screen, or right from within the Outlook Mail app), it changes the "Name" registry value at the above key. However, if I change the "Name" value in the registry (or the "Email" value, which is the one I actually want to change), this doesn't change anything in the app (or in Settings)! Even if I stop all processes and services that have that registry key open, and then make the change, and then restart without any of those processes launching... on the next boot, it's *still* using the old "Name" and "Email" values in Outlook Mail and Settings (even though my changes in the registry have persisted)!

Might be related to [Change Windows 10 "from" Address GMail](https://superuser.com/questions/948797/change-windows-10-from-address-gmail), though there's not a lot of info on that question (and no answers). I'm running the Insider Fast ring builds on my home machine, and am fine with an experimental or totally unsupported fix.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using the built-in "Outlook Mail and Calendar" app on Win10, as my employer uses G-Suite (formerly Google Apps) **and the Office version of Outlook doesn't know how to use OAuth or sync Google calendars or contacts.**

By itself, you’re right: Outlook can’t do that. But, Google has a *free* add-on called [“G-Suite Sync for Microsoft Outlook” (GSSMO)](https://support.google.com/a/users/topic/23333?hl=en&ref_topic=7394256) that gives Outlook all of those capabilities and more. It basically has Outlook treating G-Suite almost as if it were Microsoft Exchange Server!

With this add-on installed and configured, you can even turn off “Allow Less-Secure Applications” and even POP3/IMAP support in G-Suite’s Account settings, and you don’t need an Application Password! It also greatly speeds up interaction with the G-Suite servers.

Comment: That's pretty cool! Unfortunately, it fails to solve my problem in a few different ways: it requires setting up a new Outlook profile that can't sync from *non*-Google accounts (which I need, and switching profiles is annoying), it imports all my email and so on into Google (in this case, into an employer-controlled account) which I definitely don't want, and it's not actually clear whether it lets you send from non-default addresses (though I'll try it out), which is the primary reason for the question.